# OpenPop.NET - Вывод данных в приложение. (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pop3

Хотел сделать приложение, которое бы загружало с сервера сообщения и выводило их в ListBox.

До этого делал на консольном приложении и всё работало.

Если я вставляю в список обычную строку, то она тоже выводится. Но вот всё вместе работать не хочет.
Мб я что-то не правильно сделал...

Код:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="MsgCount" Margin="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20"/>
            <Button x:Name="MsgLoadButton" Margin="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" FontSize="20" Content="Загрузить" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="1,1,1,1">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="MsgListBox"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using OpenPop.Pop3;
using OpenPop.Mime;
using static System.Convert;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MsgLoadButton.Click += Load_OnClick;
        }
        private void Load_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Pop3Client Client = new Pop3Client())
            {
                try
                {
                    Client.Connect("pop.mail.ru", 995, true);
                    Client.Authenticate("mail@mail.ru", "pass");
                    int MsgOnServer = Client.GetMessageCount();
                    int NeedToLoad = ToInt32(MsgCount.Text);
                    List<string> AdressList = new List<string>();
                    for (int iter = MsgOnServer - NeedToLoad; iter == MsgOnServer; iter++)
                    {
                        AdressList.Add(Client.GetMessage(iter).Headers.From.Address);
                    }
                    MsgListBox.ItemsSource = AdressList;
                }
                catch (Exception exc) { MsgCount.Text = exc.Message; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали трассировать? Выполняется ли нужная ветка кода?

Comment: У вас неверный и очень странный цикл for. Скорее всего он ни разу не выполняется, поэтому и `AdressList` остается пустым.